# Regex to identify positive and negative numbers in an equation, but not operators

Tags: .net, regex

My program is a calculator where the user enters a string, and the output is a string of the computed value.

I need a regex to correctly identify when a number is negative, rather than the subtract operator, such that:

Input `1+2*-3-4/-5`
Would match `1, 2, -3, 4, -5`

Supported operators are `+, -, *, /. -` which is correctly match by `([+\-\*\/]{1})-?\d+`

Currently, `[+\-\*\/]{1}(-?\d+)` would match what I need except the first number.

`(\d+)[+\-\*\/](-?\d+)` however will match the first number, but incorrectly identifies the `-3` as `3`.

http://rubular.com/r/Lz6df14BeK

But now I'm kind of drawing a blank, can anyone suggest what I'm missing ?

Comment: Careful with the "-" between square brackets, you should always put it at the beginning or the end when it's inside square brackets as it means something else.

Comment: So it doesn't need to be escaped at the beginning of the brackets?  I didn't know that, thanks.

Comment: If you put it at the beginning or the end of the brackets you don't need to escape it, but if you put it in the middle, you need to escape it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this regex:

```
((?:^\-?\d+)|(?:(?<=[-+/*])(?:\-?\d+)))
```

Comment: This also does exactly as asked, thanks.  Accepted answer is the one I implemented.

Answer (score 2):

[Here's my attempt.](http://rubular.com/r/EoCIPudvo3)

```
((?<!\d)-\d+|\d+)
```

Answer (score 1):

How about this regex:

```
(?:^|[-+*/])-?\d+
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use :

```
[\+\*\-\/]?(-?+\d)
```

**[DEMO](http://rubular.com/r/1lJWGobJcl)**

**EXPLANATION :**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I used `(?<=\D|^)(-)?[0-9]+` for a similar problem but this regex will ignore whitespace between operators.